# Python 3.7 - When one counter reaches certain value 2nd counter adds one (two counters running same time)

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I have this code here working for me:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
location = 'Drive\\where-images-go\\'
N = 0

for x in range(0, 5000):
    urls = ('http://00000.IMAGE_1_'+str(x)+'.jpg')
    r = http.request('GET', urls)
    Name = str(N+1)
    N += 1
    with open(location + 'image'+Name+'_image.jpg', 'wb') as img:
      img.write(r.data)
```

This code will create a url that will count the str(x) from 0 to 5000. But I would also like to add another counter that will count by 1 for every 5000 the above counter goes up where those five zeros are. for example:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
location = 'Drive\\where-images-go\\'
N = 0

for x in range(0, 224999):
    for every 5000 in x:
        othercounter = oc
        oc = oc +1
        urls = ('http://'+str(oc)+'.IMAGE_1_'+str(x)+'.jpg')
        r = http.request('GET', urls)
        Name = str(N+1)
        N += 1
        with open(location + 'image'+Name+'_image.jpg', 'wb') as img:
          img.write(r.data)
```

So every time str(x) hits 5000 the oc(othercounter) will go up 1. As the range of the 2nd example code is (0,224999) the oc counter will be 44 and the last url will be 'http://00044.IMAGE_1_224999.jpg'. The very first image will have been 'http://00000.IMAGE_1_1.jpg'.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it is not a real image link, just a example output url : )  @Frenchy

Comment: yes i have understood after!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mod `%` to print every 5000, and I have pointed out other things you should do to achieve your goal:

1. `oc` should be initialized as `-1`, because you want to start from `0`
2. I think you want `oc` keep 5 width with prefix `0`, like `00044`, so you should use `rjust` here: `str(oc).rjust(5, '0')`
3. `0` is not necessary in `range(0, 224999)`

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
location = 'Drive\\where-images-go\\'

N = 0
oc = -1
for x in range(224999):
    N += 1
    if x % 5000 == 0:
        oc += 1

    urls = ('http://' + str(oc).rjust(5, '0') + '.IMAGE_1_' + str(N) + '.jpg')
    r = http.request('GET', urls)

    with open(location + 'image'+str(N)+'_image.jpg', 'wb') as img:
        img.write(r.data)

    # test code, need to remove
    # the first
    if x == 0:
        print('first url: {}'.format(urls))

    # the last
    if x == 224998:
        print('last url: {}'.format(urls))
```

output

```
first url: http://00000.IMAGE_1_1.jpg
last url: http://00044.IMAGE_1_224999.jpg
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you need correctly, you need but to check whenever the current number is divisible by the interval you need (in this case, 5000).

Also note that by setting the limit of the range to 5000, your first counter will only run up to 4999.

```py
other_counter = 0
for x in range(0, 15_001):  # Runs from 0 to 15000 included.
    if x % 5000 == 0:  # Results in True every time a multiple of 5000 is reached.
        other_counter += 1
```